# How do I print a word on a line, and after every second it prints the word with one extra letter on the end of it every time

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, delay

So I'm working with Python 3, and looking to make a program that has a word e.g.

```
word = 'z'
```

Then I want to have the program print the word, however every time that it prints the word, I want it to add an extra 'z' on the end, e.g.

```
>>> z
>>> zz
>>> zzz
```

Also, I want a 1 second delay between each output of the word.
I've tried to accomplish this in some ways, but they just aren't working out for me. If you have any ideas on how to do this, please share.

Comment: show us what you already have.

Comment: Don't ask he is angry programmer :)

Comment: Heard of loops? `for` or `while` loop would do what you want. In addition, also look up the time module.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is really simple using the `time` module in both **Python 2** and **Python 3**:

```
import time
c=1
word = "Hello"
print(word)
l=word[len(word)-1]
time.sleep(1)
while True:

    print(word+l*c)
    time.sleep(1)
    c+=1
```

Outputs:

```
Hello
Helloo
Hellooo
Helloooo
```

and so on...

---

#### Explanation:

- `import time` and `time.sleep()` are used for the 1-second delays
- `print(word+l*c)` inside the `while-loop` prints the word + the last character *c* times, and *c* increases by 1 each time the loop executes
- `while True` repeats continuously until the program stops executing

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know how to add a letter to a word like 'print ('Hello')' and then it prints '>>>Helloo' and adds an extra o every time? Your program seems to only work with single letters (in terms of printing what I need)

Comment: @AngryProgrammer you are responding to the answers that are being posted, so why haven't you answered the question we asked you - where is the code you wrote already to attempt this?

Comment: @takendarkk sorry, this is my first time posting here, so if I sound like I don't know what I'm doing I apologize :P Lemme post my code so far

Comment: Hello = ['hello']
HelloPlus = ['o']
for c in range(len(Hello[0])):
    HelloADD = Hello[0] + HelloPlus[0]
    print(HelloADD) @takendarkk this is my code so far, sorry I'm not sure how to post rows in the comments :P

Comment: Instead of putting it in comments you can edit your question.

Comment: @takendarkk Oh! Thanks, I'll do that from now on, and Mr.Xcoder thanks a bunch man! Thanks everyone :D

Comment: If this helped, you should **[accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it :))

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at what this code does:

```
import time

s = 'hello'
for n in range(1, len(s)+1):
    time.sleep(1)  # wait for 1 second
    print(s[:n])
```

Comment: That doesn't do what he asked.

Comment: True. Anyway, introducing `time.sleep` should be enough. I don't plan on explaining how to add a letter to a string.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the [sleep](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.sleep) function [time](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html?highlight=time#module-time) module.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time        # import time module

word = 'Hello'         # your word

while True:        # infinite loop
    print(word)    # output the word
    word += 'o'    # add 'o' to the word
    time.sleep(1)  # wait 1 seconds
```

Output

```
Hello
Helloo
Hellooo
Helloooo
```